# how do you convert a factor that has 3 digits miliseconds to datetime in R?

Tags: r

I time a t object like this:

```
t<-c("2016-10-19 00:00:00.000")
```

I need to convert to POSIXct as this:

```
as.POSIXct(t, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")

"2016-10-19 EDT"
```

I loose the hour, minute and second. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

I need this to be

```
2016-10-19  00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `lubridate` too :

```r
library(lubridate)
t<-c("2016-10-19 00:00:00.000")
ymd_hms(t)
#> [1] "2016-10-19 UTC"
```

Answer (score 5):

You didn't lose them, that's just the default for when the hours, minutes and seconds are zero.  You can specify a format string to force these to be printed:

```
> ct <- as.POSIXct(t, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
> format(ct, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2016-10-19 00:00:00"
```

Comment: this works but eventually I need to convert this to datetime, when I do that hour, minute and seconds removed. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The new and easy-to-use package `anytime` is an alternative:

```
library(anytime) 
anydate(t$Datetime)
```